# Meteor: Pick the same random item from an array in a method and its simulation

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Using the [Random](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/random.html) package or any other techniques, is there a way to pick the same item from an array on the Client and the Server (for optimistic UI purposes)?

Example:

```
Meteor.methods({
    myMethod(): {
        var item = Random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4]); // Should return 2 on both client and server
    },
});
```

I know that Meteor [uses a specific seed](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#consistent-id-generation) for every method invocation  to generate the same _id for a document from the Client and the Server. So there must be a way to accomplish this!

Comment: Does the server has to invoke the choice by method? Means, would it violate any security if the client generates the pick and just send the result to the server afterwards?

Comment: @Jankapunkt This could work yes, but I'm still wondering if the original problem can be solved.